# Arithmetic not being done on first dictionary entry?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class creditCard:
    def __init__(self, limit, apr, balance):
        self.limit = limit
        self.apr = apr
        self.balance = balance
        self.charges = {}
        self.payments = {}

    def charge(self, amount, day):
        # Charges the card, and stores the charge and day the charge was made in a dictionary.
        # Returns false if the amount charged is greater than the limit.

        if amount > self.limit - self.balance:
            return False

        self.charges[day] = amount
        self.balance += amount

    def payment(self, amount, day):
        # When a payment is made the payment is stored in the payments dictionary with the corresponding day.
        # Returns false is the payment amount is greater than the balance owed/limit.

        if amount > self.limit - self.balance:
            return False

        self.payments[day] = amount
        self.balance -= amount

    def interest(self, balance):
        # calculates and returns interest

        return (balance * self.apr) / 365

    def days_balance(self, balance_day):
        balance_to_date = 0
        months_interest = 0
        for day in range(1, balance_day+1):
            balance_to_date += self.charges.get(day, 0)
            balance_to_date -= self.payments.get(day, 0)
            months_interest += self.interest(balance_to_date)

            if day % 30 == 0:
                balance_to_date += months_interest
                months_interest = 0


        balance_to_date = round(balance_to_date, 2)

        return "${}".format(balance_to_date)
```

I am supposed to be returning 411.99 for my second test case and I am getting 411.89 due to the dictionary not applying the interest for the first day. I can not figure out why it is doing that what so ever. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my test case.

- customer opens a credit card with 1k limit and 35% APR
- customer charges $500 on opening day
- 15 days after opening he pays $200 (balance now 300)
- 25 days after opening he charges another $100 (balance now 400)
- total balance at the end of the month is 411.99

  ```
  customer1 = creditCard(1000, 0.35, 0)
  customer1.charge(500, 1)
  print(customer1.days_balance(30))
  for i in customer1.charges:
     print(customer1.charges.keys(), customer1.charges.values())

  customer2 = creditCard(1000, 0.35, 0)
  customer2.charge(500, 1)
  customer2.payment(200, 15)
  customer2.charge(100, 25)
  print("Customers Balance on Day 26: " + customer2.days_balance(26))
  print("Customers Balance on Day 30 with Interest: " + 
   customer2.days_balance(30))
  ```

Comment: Try printing out your dict to see if it is setting the day you think it is. Since you're starting your range loop at 1, it's possible the first day is being marked as zero.

Comment: Can you share your test cases?

Comment: Edited with my test cases. @robbrit I have printed out my dictionary and interest is applied on day 0 but I think it is not applying it on day number 30 due to the if statement?

Comment: If `charge` returns `False` for a declined charge, it should return `True` for an processed charge. While you can distinguish between `False` and `None`, distinguishing `False` and `True` is much easier.

Comment: Ah yes, it is ignoring the 30th day because `30 % 30 == 0`.

Comment: How should I go about making it count the 30th day? Would I just add another interest call in the if statement?

Comment: Just do `day % 31 == 0` if you want to always count the 30th day. However if you want to have this work for real-world data, consider using the `datetime` class instead of fiddling with integers.

Comment: the problem with doing 31 is that the interest has to be applied on the 30th day. (one of the stipulations of the assignment)